# How can I have a routing like this controller/action/id/string in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, controller

I have a actionresult that look this:

```
public ActionResult Comment(int id)
{
    var news = re.GetNewsByID(id);
    NewsViewModel model = new NewsViewModel();

    model.Description = news.Description;
    model.Imageurl = news.Image;
    model.link = news.Link;
    model.PubDate = news.Date;
    model.Title = news.Title;

    return View(model);
}
```

and inside the view I have declared:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Comment", "Comment", new { id = item.Title })
```

When I click on the actionlink I get to the following url:

```
Home/Comment/403
```

But I want it to end with the item.title.

Something like this:

```
Home/Comment/403/What-ever-the-item-title-contains
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would 1st map that route in my Routes Collection:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Title",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 0, title = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Make sure this route in mapped UNDER your default route. Once you have this then just do:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Comment", "Comment", new { id = item.Id, title = item.Title })
```

For that matter you might just want to make your default route look like the route I made above. There is no need for 2 routes since both ID and Title are optional.

Comment: One should be careful with multiple optional route parameters as it can lead to some shifty things -http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx  If both params will be needed for this route, don't mark them optional

Comment: Hmmm wasn't aware of this bug/issue. Thanks for the link Tommy. I still think that in Juliano's case he needs a 2nd route that has id parameter that is not optional but title parameter that is optional since having a title makes no sense without having an item ID. That resolves the issue with the bug and solves his problem. By the way is this bug still an issue in MVC 4?

Comment: @Marko, One question, if a item have same title but different ID. will it lead to shifty things?

Comment: @Obsivus I don't see why it would. Your method is called GetNewsByID so your primary key is still ID. Title is irrelevant... I have updated my original post so that the ID route value is now not optional as Tommy has suggested.

Comment: @Marko When I tried your code everything is fine beside that my master page.cshtml is not working anymore. so there is no css or anything :S

Comment: @Obsivus What do you mean your master is not working? Do you get a 404 error or are your css styles just broken? What is the controller/action that renders this page? What url are you trying when the page fails?

Comment: I get to link everything fine beside there is no css styles, sorry about the master page, it is working but its the css that got messed up after the change :S

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30092/discussion-between-marko-and-obsivus)

Comment: @Marko do you have time for some chat? :)

Answer (score 0):

I never knew how to do it from `Html.ActionLink`, I always used `Url.Action` like so:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Comment", new { id = item.Title })/@theTermToAddHere">Comment</a>
```

Note the "/" in the href is the markup (not a part of the Razor code), and then I append the additional term.